# Bluemix - NSF .XSP Application display Error 403 after git push

Tags: git, xpages, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

After I pushed my modified NSF file to Bluemix service I got:

> Error 403
>
> HTTP Web Server: You are forbidden to perform this operation

This is a list of operations performed:

- Downloaded a sample app
- Set up git repository
- Cloned
- Modified an app (changing images on main page)
- Pushed it back

It seems like problem with application signing. Any advice?

Comment: Where is the sample app you used?

Comment: I used sample app from cloned project repository. The same file is available in my xsp project -> start coding -> download starter code.

Comment: Where is the original sample repository?

Comment: @ShirouWrath - Have you solved your issue? Did you see the question that joe had posted previously?